# From where can I start my journey into the feild of networking and hacking?

Tags: linux, networking

Are there any good books or maybe online courses to start with for learning about linux and networking protocols like ssh and other things like onion, where should I start ? Which tool should I learn first, if you know, pls help me out !

Answer (score 0):

Check out "SSH, The Secure Shell - The Definitive Guide to SSH" here: https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/ssh/index.htm